# WPF как работать с UI без остановки его потока

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, async-await

В случае когда моя программа выполняет ресурсоемкие задачи я пускаю их в отдельном потоке и все гуд. НО появился такой случай когда контролу я присваиваю довольно большую коллекцию да еще и составную из объектов и в тот момент с одной стороны я не могу пустить эту работу в отдельном потоке с другой UI намертво подвисает секунд на 5.

```
ListView1.ItemsSource = objectsListForBindingAll;
```

Как быть в таких случаях? одна лишь эта команда тормозит все на  секунд, а я хотел бы показать прогресс бар неопределенный вместо тормозов?

Comment: Советую сделать как в [этой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dn605875.aspx) статье.

Comment: Сама по себе такая команда не может тормозить UI надолго. Выкатите воспроизводящий пример, чтобы было понятно, что вы делаете не так. Может быть, у вас последовательность генерируется динамически с запросом к базе? Или может быть вы хотите показать юзеру миллион элементов в невиртуальном ListView? Мало ли какие могут быть ошибки.

Comment: Влад, ваша ссылка к сож. не подходит ко мне.
ВладДэ я не могу показать пример потому что это долго и нет в этом смысла. У меня есть List<T> objectsListForBindingAll который собирается в отдельном потоке до того как я его присваиваю листВью и я могу вас заверить подвисание окна происходит во время этого присваивание. В тот момент никаких других операций не происходит. Элементов не миллион, а около тысячи, но видимо и этого достаточно для тормозов, потому что элементы составные а не тупо строки.

Comment: Почему нельзя сначала собирать вашу коллекцию в отдельном потоке, а после уже потом отображать ее?

Comment: Bulson, епт я так и делаю если бы вы внимательнее читали пост)

Comment: @beatsspam: Ну, если вы не приведёте воспроизводящий пример, то нам будет сложно помочь. У меня, например, в коде список из 1000 элементов не представляет вообще никакой проблемы, так что проблема не в количестве. Так что в ваших же интересах сделать так, чтобы проблема воспроизвелась у нас.

Comment: ВладДэ хорошо сегодня вечером как освобожусь залью пример.

Comment: Вот залил наконец пример https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq6ZQkyoPcuM9BWOF3mQIbX_JOrQ буду рад если посмотрите. К слову сейчас я за своим персональным ПК, тут работает довольно шустро, подвисает всего на секунду, а вот на ноуте проверял там 2 ядра виснет 5-7 секунд. См. кнопку шаг 2 в моей проге.

Comment: @beatsspam: А вы не могли бы выложить пример прямо в вопрос? У меня на работе onedrive заблокирован.

Comment: ВладДэ блин вам не угодишь( Я не умею, даже не подозревал что на этом сайте можно загружать файлы( Попробуйте воспользоваться анонимайзерами сайтами или брауером тором. способом же полно в интернете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте на форму нормальный датагрид, который умеет виртуализировать. Все сделано в пару кликов было. Создайте источник данных для объекта Objects.cs и перетащите лист на форму. Всё создадется автоматом .

```
 <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource rootObjectLekarstvoViewSource}">
        <DataGrid x:Name="listDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource rootObjectLekarstvolistViewSource}}" Margin="0,109,117,10" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="byeLinkColumn" Binding="{Binding byeLink}" Header="bye Link" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="drug_codeColumn" Binding="{Binding drug_code}" Header="drug code" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="isOnColumn" Binding="{Binding isOn}" Header="is On" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="online_storeColumn" Binding="{Binding online_store}" Header="online store" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="priceColumn" Binding="{Binding price}" Header="price" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="reserveLinkColumn" Binding="{Binding reserveLink}" Header="reserve Link" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="updatedColumn" Binding="{Binding updated}" Header="updated" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
```

```
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var json = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("http://contrib.gpor.ru/pharmacyImport/feed/pharmacyFeed_60.json");
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectLekarstvo>(json);
        listDataGrid.ItemsSource = data.list;
    }
```

На выходе 10к данных загрузилось из интернета и добавилось в таблицу асинхронно, интерфейс не подвисал.

Comment: Интересный вариант заменить ListView на DataGrid, и он работает. Сомневаюсь что асинхронно, просто DataGrid отрабатывает очень быстро и UI не успевает останавливаться на видимое время. Впринцыпе пока тогда так и сделаю. Спасибо

Comment: Он не быстрее работает, он виртуализирует и подгружает при необходимости. Кстати, расход памяти оперативной ощутимо меньше идёт. У вас при 10к значениях около гигабайта съедало и всё равно не отображало данные.

Answer (score 2):

Если коллекция большая и тормозит UI при попытке ее отобразить целиком, то напрашивается разбиение этой коллекции на части и последовательное отображение частей, т.е так называемая пагинация.

Answer (score 0):

А запустить это добавления асинхронно не выходит? Например вот так await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, ()=>
{
Сюда добавление списка
});

Comment: Я хотел бы проверить ваш метод, но к сожалению "Ошибка CS1061 'Dispatcher" не содержит определения для "RunAsync" и не удалось найти метод расширения "RunAsync"". Вероятно это не для десктоп программ а для стора.

Comment: await Task.Factory тоже нет? Либо с диспетчером попробуйте InvokeAsync(). Прочитайте про асинхронное программирование, возможно вы упустили какой -либо момент. Как вариант, создайте асинхронный метод. private Task SetItemsSource(){ здесь вставьте ваше присваивание}. В коде вызовите его через await. И да, если эта операция не будет выполняться в пользовательском потоке (не будет вызвана действием пользователя), то будет ошибка. Вызов UI из другого потока только через диспетчер реализуется. Это так, на будущее, может спасет вам пару часов времени:)

Comment: проверил все что ты перечислил. тоже нет( При выполнении как ты сказал из другого потока ничего не тормозит но ошибка, а из UI работает но тормозит. Если засунуть в другом потоке в диспечер Invoke

Comment: Если засунуть в другом потоке в диспечер Invoke то опять же управление вернет команду в UI поток и UI соотвествено повиснет(. В комментарии к 1му посту я прикрепил ссылку на исходники программы если у вас будет время посмотреть и проверить у себя